# Why is Preview blacking out pages in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, preview

Someone sent me a PDF. Here's what it looks like in Preview. I can see the pages in the thumbnails, but in the main window they are black. Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it.

When the program first opens the file, I see the pages for a fraction of a second before it blacks them out.

[image]

**Update**

I tried calibrating my displays, as suggested in a comment, but the pages are still black. I have two monitors - the MacBook Pro's screen and an external display.

Comment: See related:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303818/why-are-jpeg-pdf-documents-being-covered-with-solid-black-rectangles

Comment: One difference in my case is that the Finder preview is working fine.

Comment: This could be caused by the original doc being scanned in Image Capture. I've [seen some people with this problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8101846) resolve it by re-calibrating their display.  Go to `System Preferences > Displays > Color`, and click the Calibrate button.  See if that helps and then update the question with those results.

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: How is it with other apps that display PDFs ... Adobe Reader, for example?

Comment: It looks fine in Safari and Adobe Reader. I guess I'll use one of those, but I'm familiar with Preview and would prefer to use it if possible.

Comment: This has hit me suddenly today on latest Monterey. Literally any and all pdfs are coming out black, and yesterday it was all good.

Answer (score 2):

Years later - I'm facing this very issue on latest Monterey and M1 MBP.

For me - the cause was another application that consumed ~10GB of RAM, and when I tried to use it - it had (different)rendering problems instead.

Force-quitting the misbehaving app helped Preview render the PDFs normally again.

I've tried other suggestions such as removing certain stuff in `~/Library` but I couldn't find any of these.

Comment: This is totally bizarre but closing a few applications worked for me as well.  (Looking at you docker desktop!!!)

Comment: Back here to search for my own answer :D It worked again!